# Use same future for several FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

In my page I have many FutureBuilder that share the same data from a future. As the future is a request from Firebase, I just want to do it one time. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: you can get the data from first FutureBuilder and pass the data through the widget tree.

Comment: All FutureBuilder are in the same widget

Comment: can you share some code as expamle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you FutureBuilder calls the future, you can store its value inside a variable.

After that, you can pass that variable in your widgets via the constructor or if you are in the same stateful widget then you can directly assign it via setstate method.

Comment: Should I initialize the future in initState and then call it in all futureBuilder ?

Comment: Yes you should always initialize your future in initstate that way your future won't be called infinite times and it will save you some memory and performance